# CSS for table headers sometimes disappears when pressing submit button on Edge

Tags: html, css

Really weird error. My table headers for agencytable sometimes lose their CSS when I click the submit button for a non-existent USN and the alert message pops up. I can't reproduce the error on Google Chrome, it only happens on Edge. The CSS seems to disappear randomly, too. It's not that some numbers work while some don't. It works fine when I enter an existing USN.

```js
$(document).ready(function($) {
  $('#agencytablelevelselect').change(function() {
    $('table').show();
    var selection = $(this).val();
    var dataset = $('#agencytable tbody').find('tr');
    dataset.show();
    dataset.filter(function(index, item) {
      return $(item).find('td:first-child').text().indexOf(selection) === -1;
    }).hide();
  });


});

function filter() {
  inp = $('#agencytablenameselect').val();
  $("tr:not(:has(>th))").each(function() {
    if (~$(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(inp.toLowerCase())) {
      $(this).show();
    } else {
      $(this).hide();
    }
  });
}

window.onload = function invalidUSNPop() {
  var inputVal = document.getElementById("input").value;

  console.log(inputVal);
  if (inputVal.trim() == '') {
    return;
  }

  <?php if ($userdata[0]['USN'] == null): ?>
  alert("존재하지 않는 USN/Email입니다");
  <?php endif; ?>
}
```

```css
.refersubmit {
  background-color: white;
}

.ranklist {
  height: 30px;
  width: 60px;
}

.pill-nav a {
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: gray;
  border-style: solid;
  float: left;
}

.searchnav input[type=text] {
  float: left;
  margin-top: 10px;
  height: 30px;
}

.searchnav button {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 10px;
  height: 30px;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.searchnav {
  width: 20%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.agencytable th {
  background-color: gray;
  height: 30px;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  /*margin-left: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;*/
  border-style: solid;
}

.agencytable td {
  height: 30px;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  /*margin-left: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;*/
  border-style: solid;
}

.agencytable {
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.tablebar input[type=text] {
  height: 30px;
}

.tablebar {
  float: left;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  clear: both;
}

.tablebar button {
  height: 30px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  float: right;
}

.f1close {
  color: black;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.f1close:hover,
.f1close:focus {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<main role="main">
  <h1 class="">유저 에이전시 정보</h1>

  <div class="searchnav">
    <div class="pill-nav">
      <a>USN/Email</a>
      <form method='post' action='/useragencyinfo/search'>
        <input id="input" name="inUSN" type="text" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['inUSN']) ? $_POST['inUSN'] : '' ?>">
        <button class="submit" type="submit">검색</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>

  <br>




  <div>

    <body style="min-width: 2000px;">
      <table class="agencytable">

        <tr>
          <th id="user-usn">USN</th>
          <td>
            <?php echo $userdata[0]['USN'] ?>
          </td>
          <th id="user-email">Email</th>
          <td>
            <?php echo $userdata[0]['Email'] ?>
          </td>
          <th id="user-nickname">닉네임</th>
          <td>
            <?php echo $userdata[0]['Name'] ?>
          </td>
          <th id="user-rank">Rank</th>
          <td>
            <?php echo $userdata[0]['RankLevel'] ?>
          </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <th id="user-mybet">MyBet Commission</th>
          <?php $userdata[0]['MyBetCommission'] == null ? $val = null : $val = number_format($userdata[0]['MyBetCommission'], 2) ?>
          <td>
            <?php echo $val ?>
          </td>

          <th id="user-myagency">MyAgency Commission</th>
          <?php $userdata[0]['MyAgencyCommission'] == null ? $val = null : $val = number_format($userdata[0]['MyAgencyCommission'], 2) ?>
          <td>
            <?php echo $val ?>
          </td>

          <th id="user-agency">Agency Commission</th>
          <?php $userdata[0]['AgencyCommission'] == null ? $val = null : $val = number_format($userdata[0]['AgencyCommission'], 2) ?>
          <td>
            <?php echo $val ?>
          </td>
        </tr>

      </table>
  </div>

  <div class="tablebar">
    <a style="width: 150px">Referral Level</a>
    <form style="display: inline-block" method='post' action='/useragencyinfo/search'>
      <select id="agencytablelevelselect" class="ranklist" name="selReferLevel">
        <option value="">-</option>
        <option value="1">F1</option>
        <option value="2">F2</option>
        <option value="3">F3</option>
        <option value="4">F4</option>
        <option value="5">F5</option>
        <option value="6">F6</option>
        <option value="7">F7</option>
        <option value="8">F8</option>
      </select>
      <a>Username</a>
      <input id="agencytablenameselect" type="text" name="inputusername" placeholder="Enter Username" onkeyup="filter()">
    </form>
  </div>

  <br>

  <div style="margin-top: 50px;">

    <table id="agencytable" style="margin-top: 70px;" class="agencytable">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th style="width: 70px;">Lv</th>
          <th style="width: 120px;">Username</th>
          <th style="width: 70px;">Rank</th>
          <th>Volume</th>
          <th>Total Commission</th>
          <th style="width: 120px;">미성산 커미션</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>

      <tbody>
        <?php   if (!empty($referraldata) && count($referraldata) > 0): ?>
          <?php foreach ($referraldata AS $idx => $row): ?>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <?php echo $row['Lv'] ?>
            </td>
            <td>
              <?php echo $row['Username'] ?>
            </td>
            <td>
              <?php echo $row['Rnk'] ?>
            </td>
            <td>
              <?php echo number_format($row['Volume'], 2) ?>
            </td>
            <td>
              <?php echo number_format($row['TotalCommission'], 2) ?>
            </td>
            <td>
              <?php echo number_format($row['UncalcCommission'], 2) ?>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <?php endforeach; ?>
          <?php else: ?>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="6">No Result</td>
          </tr>
          <?php endif; ?>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <div>
```

Comment: Please specify what elements lose their CSS values. You should be aware that CSS has unique flags for browsers compatibility

Comment: All the th's with class agencytable are losing their CSS.

Comment: I understand that the CSS is changed on the new DOM that is rendered on the post-action page, right?

Comment: Yes that's right. After clicking confirm on the alert the page goes back to normal